# Custom cursor for a text component in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, cursor

Hi I'm trying to make an Password pin component in compose, and after trying to do this with a normal Textfield i realized it has certain limitations and i'd rather do it with a normal Text component and add a custom cursor.

However i've come across a problem and i'm not sure how to solve it

This is my custom cursor

```
  Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(1.dp)
        .height(24.dp)
        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
            val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                placeable.placeRelative(0.dp.roundToPx(),
                    (-40).dp.roundToPx())
            }
        }
        .background(color = cursorColor)
)
```

The text component

```
 Text(
    text = text,
    color = Color.Black,
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(Width)
        .height(44.dp)
)
```

And an underline component

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = color)
        .height(1.dp)
        .width(Width)
)
```

They are all inside a box, the order is Text -> Underline-> Cursor
The problem is that after I input all numbers in the text component and the cursor dissapears the whole numpad(another custom component) moves up by a few pixels. How can I avoid this?

Are there any other better approaches to creating a custom cursor?

I'm pretty stuck on this, any ideas please?